# How to add parameter for postgres enum types in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Hi currently have the problem, that I want to insert values in a postgres database where the table contains self defined types like.

```
CREATE TYPE TestEnum AS ENUM ('Value1','Value2');
```

When I try to add a parameter in C# I always get an error because of the wrong NpgsqlDbType. So my question is what NpgsqlDbType to use for such self defined Types.

```
var parameter = new NpgsqlParameter(":p1", NpgsqlDbType.????)
{
    Value = "Value1",
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
}
```

Thanks for your help. I'm really going mad because of this problem.

Comment: After all, I found a solution that solves the problem, although it's not the real solution. I now add a NpgsqlDbType.Varchar parameter and add a CAST(:p1 as "TestEnum") to the SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all, I found a solution that solves the problem, although it's not the real solution. 
I now add a NpgsqlDbType.Varchar parameter and add a CAST(:p1 as "TestEnum") to the SQL

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO tableName (Col) VALUES ( CAST(:p1 as "TestEnum") )
```

It works for me, although I do not think that this is a very nice solution due to the cast.
If someone will find a better solution in future, please drop me a line. ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to **[PostgreSQL 8.4.4 Documentation: 8.7. Enumerated Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html)**:

> An enum value occupies four bytes on disk.

That suggests that they are internally stored as a **32-bit integer**. It uses the system catalog `pg_enum` to map from integers to the names and back.

Unfortunately, the **[documentation for NpgsqlDbType](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/api/NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.html)** does not elucidate the meaning of each of those enum values, but my guess would be that `NpgsqlDbType.Integer` is likely to refer to a 32-bit integer.

However, I must confess that I am guessing here. It is also possible that `NpgsqlParameter` expects a type that represents the data you send to the DB with the query, which is clearly a string, so if `NpgsqlDbType.Integer` doesn’t work, my next guess would be `NpgsqlDbType.Varchar`.

Comment: That's the problem. Neither of both are working. So there must be another solution for it.

Comment: It always tells the following message: FEHLER: 42804: Spalte »TypeEnum« hat Typ "TestEnum", aber der Ausdruck hat Typ character varying

That's so strange ... Do you have another idea?